# How to set caret position in middle of word after regenerating innerHTML within contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, dom, caret

I am regenerating innerHTML with every keystroke in order to wrap words from innerText with spans. I do this to search for keywords that have different style.

```
 process() {
    this.content.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.text.split(" ").map((word, index) => {
      let wrapped;
      if (this.elements.map(e => e.name).includes(word)) {
        wrapped = `<span style="color: darkblue; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">${word}</span>`
      } else {
        wrapped = `<span style="cursor: pointer;">${word}</span>`
      }
      if (word === this.word) {
        this.spanIndex = index;
      }
      return wrapped;
    }).join(" ");
    this.setCaretPosition();
    this.addInnerHTMLListeners();
  }
```

Within the process function I set back the caret position.

```
setCaretPosition() {
    this.target.focus();
    var lastNode = this.content.nativeElement.childNodes[this.nodeIndex];
    var range = document.createRange();
    const letterIndex = this.letterIndex;
    console.log(letterIndex, lastNode.childNodes.length)
    range.setStart(lastNode, letterIndex); //lastNode.childNodes.length
    range.setEnd(lastNode, letterIndex);
    range.collapse(true);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
```

It works great with `lastNode.childNodes.length` when the cursor should be at the end of a word.
But when I am in middle of it I dont know how to do that.
Since when I am at position 2 (third letter) then setting it at 2 will result in 
`ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': There is no child at offset 2.`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Didnt realize the DOM was more complicated.

The innerHTML of the div consists of spans like this:
`<span style="color: darkblue; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">${word}</span>`

I knew which span it is 
`var node = this.content.nativeElement.childNodes[this.nodeIndex];`

But to set the caret inside the word I need to get its first child which is probably text

```
var range = document.createRange();
console.log(node, node.firstChild, this.letterIndex)
range.setStart(node.firstChild, this.letterIndex);
range.setEnd(node.firstChild, this.letterIndex);
```